# How can I display the full state/province instead of just the abbreviation when a user chooses an address in google autocomplete API.

Tags: c#, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

After a uses has selected a address, I am displaying a form so they can fix any issues in the address if necessary.

1. The user chooses an address.
   [image: The user chooses an address]
2. The form is displayed so the user can modify the address if necessary.
   [image: The form is displayed so the user can modify the address if necessary]

I want to display the full state/province instead of abbreviation, is it that possible using the API, or do I need to create a dictionary to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: You would be better off to create a simple dictionary. It might be a little tedious to write, but it really is not that much code to put it in a function call.

Comment: I created the dictionary, but I decided to go with the solution proposed by @kaho, thank you =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is the `componentForm` you have to change.

in the documentation's example, 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform

componentForm is setted as follow:

```
var componentForm = {
  street_number: 'short_name',
  route: 'long_name',
  locality: 'long_name',
  administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
  country: 'long_name',
  postal_code: 'short_name'
};
```

if I change `administrative_area_level_1` from `'short_name'` to `'long_name'`, then the states would be in its full name.
http://jsfiddle.net/x1sx3p40/

[image]

hope this help!